# Populating TableView with NSMutableSet

Tags: objective-c, core-data, tableview, nsmutableset

I am using core data and trying to populate a `UITableView` with an `NSMutableSet`. I have two entities, **Teams** and **Players**. On my `addTeamsController` I am saving a player to the team as follows

```
-(void)saveButtonWasPressed {
    self.team =[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Team" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    Player *newPlayer = (Player *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Player" 
                                                                inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    team.schoolName = _schoolName.text;
    team.teamName = _teamName.text;
    team.teamID = _teamName.text;
    team.season =  _season.text;
    team.headCoach = _headCoach.text;
    team.astCoach = _assistantCoach.text;


    [self.team addPlayers:_tempSet];

    [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];    
}
```

On another viewController I am trying to populate a tableview with that teams players. To do that I am doing as follows

```
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
_array = [[_team.players allObjects] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

and then on my cell for row and index path I am doing the following

```
    cell.textLabel.text = [_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

And I get the error

```
[Player  isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I am wondering what the best approach to filling the tableview sorted by the players first names is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to populate a table from a core data store is to use an `NSFetchedResultController`. But that is not going to fix the problem you're having, the problem is that your trying to set `cell.textLabel.text` to an `NSManagedObject`, which doesn't work.  You can set

```
cell.textLabel.text = Player.someStringAttribute
```